# What is the meaning of NumberFormatException and how I can resolve it?

Tags: java, python, bash, weblogic, wlst

I'm writing code in Python/WLST to automatize connection, staringt and stopping of managed severs in weblogic. I've get the error below when I start Python.

What is the meaning of the exception and how i can resolve it?

> Initializing WebLogic Scripting Tool (WLST) ...
>
> Welcome to WebLogic Server Administration Scripting Shell
>
> Type help() for help on available commands
>
> 172.31.138.15:7001
>
> Connecting to t3://172.31.138.15:7001  with userid weblogic ...
>
> WLST detected that the RuntimeMBeanServer is not enabled. This might
>   happen if the RuntimeMBeanServer is disabled via the JMXMBean. Please
>   ensure that this MBeanServer is enabled. Online WLST cannot function
>   without this MBeanServer. This Exception occurred at Mon Jan 13
>   08:52:50 CET 2020. java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:
>   "7001 "
>
> The domain is unreacheable

The code:

-bash

```
#! /bin/sh

echo $(find /u01/ -name config.xml |grep -v bak| xargs grep -A4 AdminServer | grep listen-address | cut -d'>' -f 2 | cut -d'<' -f 1)
```

-Python/WLST

```
import sys
import os
from java.lang import System
import getopt
import time

values = os.popen(str('sh /home/oracle/scripts/wls/adminurl.sh'))
url = str("".join(map(str, values)))
port = ":7001"

adminurl = url.rstrip() + port + "\n"

def connectToDomain():
    try:
        if ServerName != "" or username == "" and password == "" and adminUrl == "":
            print (adminurl)
            connect(userConfigFile='/home/oracle/scripts/wls/userconfig.secure', userKeyFile='/home/oracle/scripts/wls/userkey.secure', url=adminurl, timeout=60000)

[...]
```

Moreover, RuntimeMBeanServer is enabled in Adminserver console

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be caused by `adminurl = url.rstrip() + port + "\n"`. Try without \n.

Explanation of assumption: adminUrl can later be split into several parts by ":" symbol. In that case, it would try to parse 7001\n as int, and, well, would fail in some method like java.lang.Integer#parseInt(java.lang.String)